# Why expected `isize` in the procedural macro `u32_suffixed` error report?

Tags: rust

I wrote such a macro with a test example like this:

```rs
#[selector]
pub enum Action {
    A = "a()",
    B = "b()",
}
```

The `selector` implementation:

```rs
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn selector(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(item as ItemEnum);

    let ItemEnum { attrs, vis, enum_token, ident, variants, .. } = input;

    let mut ident_vec: Vec<Ident> = Vec::new();
    let mut hash_vec: Vec<Expr> = Vec::new();

    let mut count = 0u32;
    for variant in variants {
        count = count + 1;
        if let Some((_, Expr::Lit(lit))) = variant.discriminant {
            let ExprLit { attrs, lit } = lit;
            if let Lit::Str(lit_str) = lit {
                ident_vec.push(variant.ident);

                hash_vec.push(Expr::Lit(ExprLit {
                    attrs: Default::default(),
                    // lit: Lit::Verbatim(Literal::u32_unsuffixed(count)),  // works
                    lit: Lit::Verbatim(Literal::u32_suffixed(count)),   // compile error
                }));
            }
        }
    }

    (quote! {
        #vis #enum_token #ident {
            #(
                #ident_vec = #hash_vec
            ),*
        }
    })
    .into()
}
```

The compile error report:

```rs
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> macros/generate-actions/tests/tests.rs:6:2
  |
6 |     #[generate_actions::selector]
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |     |
  |     expected `isize`, found `u32`
  |     in this procedural macro expansion
  |
 ::: /home/bear/working/darwinia/play-rust/macros/generate-actions/src/lib.rs:8:1
  |
8 | pub fn selector(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
  | -------------------------------------------------------------------- in this expansion of `#[generate_actions::selector]`
  |
help: change the type of the numeric literal from `u32` to `isize`
  |
6 |     #[generate_actions::selector]isize
```

I want to know why `u32_suffixed` will trigger such a compile error?

Comment: Because you're generating code equivalent to this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5579fe7f91866a680aa6d32a375aae50)

Comment: From the report: `expected isize, found u32`. How to understand this `isize`? I did not find `isize` usage in the marco.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the macro, my playground example shows the same error without any macros. Enum discriminants are supposed to be `isize`: see the [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/enumerations.html#custom-discriminant-values-for-fieldless-enumerations).

Comment: Thanks! I have learned from this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with the fact that you're using a macro. The issue is that the macro generates code similar to this:

```
enum Foo {
    A = 0u32,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5579fe7f91866a680aa6d32a375aae50)

Which triggers the same error. However according to the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/enumerations.html#custom-discriminant-values-for-fieldless-enumerations), enum discriminants are supposed to have type `isize`:

```
enum Foo {
    A = 0,        // Automatically inferred as `isize`
    B = 1isize,   // OK
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=8cb81dedc6ab82bc6f9b6f45764e8ef2)